# Error number 500

Tags: php, html, web

I am getting this console error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

And also the content of my site is not visible. Since this is my fist time uploading and playing with these website stuff, I am not able to figure out where my mistake is.

The same thing runs perfectly on my localhost.

Here is the screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Try checking file permissions. File permission should be 644 and folder permission should be 755.

Comment: ok..i guess that's the problem

Comment: Check your error log. It could be a different PHP version running on your server. We can't help you without code/ the error.

Comment: i checked it ....

[Sun Oct 16 01:57:15.509213 2016] [:error] [pid 2318] [client 103.56.252.253:26504] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /var/www/html/vendor/illuminate/database/Capsule/Manager.php on line 199

but i dont think thats the problem

Comment: @RishabhAnand, Thats exactly the problem. You have an Internal Server Error. A parse error qualifies. You could edit your question with the relevant part of the file if you want more help with debugging the issue.

Comment: What platform? Enable PHP Error logging, you will get an idea of what could be causing the problem.

Comment: sir...i got it solved
and thankyoufor stopping by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error (404) indicates the image URL is not found, make sure you write the image URL properly.

For the second error, refer to this [link](https://www.1and1.com/cloud-community/learn/web-server/server-management/how-to-fix-http-error-code-500-internal-server-error/)
as you may have an issue with file permissions or your .htaccess file